# Como puedo Cerrar venta de email con java Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy intentando cerrar una ventana de email y utilice este codigo pero no logra cerrar.

```
Set<String> wnd = getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    // window handles iteration
    Iterator<String> i = wnd.iterator();
    prntw = i.next();
    popwnd = i.next();
    // switching pop up window handle id
    getDriver().switchTo().window(popwnd);
    System.out.println("Nombre de Pestana "+ getDriver().getTitle());
    // closes pop up window
    getDriver().close();
    // switching parent window handle id
    getDriver().switchTo().window(prntw);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quiero cerrar las 2 ventanas

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Estoy automatizando con java selenium.
Estoy haciendo click en compartir anuncio por correo, le da click se cierra el navegador pero se queda abierto las 2 ventanas de agregar cuenta y la ventana grande.

Comment: @Comunidad si esta claro?